# Is there a way to code Ctrl+a :multiuser on when using screen?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I want to run a script that sets up a screen session and then automatically makes it into a multi-user and also adds one of the users on my system.

So far, I have a script that creates the screen session, but I have to manually make it into a multiuser session then also add the user.

As far as I have seen there is no actual coding to do this and the only way to do it is with the Ctrl+a command.

Does anyone know of a way that means the command can be done in a bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can automatically run custom commands from a configuration file - by default `$HOME/.screenrc` will be loaded, if it exists, so you can just do:

```
echo "multiuser on" >> $HOME/.screenrc
```

to make your default screen start with `:multiuser on`. If you want to have a separate config from the default, just save the config with an alternative filename, and start screen with the `-c` option, e.g.

```
screen -c multiuser.conf
```

Comment: I added at the end of my code `echo "multiuser on" >> $HOME/.screenrc` and then after that added `echo "acladd richardanderson" >> $HOME/.screenrc`. This still did not allow the user to access the screen. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't run these commands from a script, since that would mean these lines would be always appended to the `.screenrc` file each time the script is run, which is unnecessary. It's enough to just edit it once - if the file contains the commands for multiuser and acladd that should be enough, and the next screen session that is started will use the options.

Comment: What If I just want a certain screen session to start with these options?

Comment: Then save the config to a different location / with a different name, and start screen with the `-c` option specifying the alternative config file.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it without entering the screen, using `-X`. The following lines (run by Alice) start a script in a screen and add access for the user `bob`.

```
screen -S "myscreen" -dm bash script-that-i-like.sh
screen -S "myscreen" -X multiuser on
screen -S "myscreen" -X acladd bob
```

Bob can then join using:

```
screen -x alice/myscreen
```